# How can I update the mat-table when the formarray datasource edited?

Tags: angular, typescript

[Here is the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ptolemy-wpcsoq?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

I have a mat-table with 2 columns, once with a mat-input-field, once just rending the formcontrol value.

When I change the formcontrol value with a button method, the first column change, the second one doesn't.

How can I update the column of rending value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using data source as a copy of initialized values of the form and reflecting this in the mat-table.
Your button click event changes only form data, not the data source.
Since mat-table's data source is not affected by these changes, it has nothing different to show.

When you update your data source value in the button click event, it would be reacted as you wish.

```
this.dataSource.data = this.tableForm.get('elements')?.value;
```

Comment: Is there any difference bewtween
`this.dataSource.data = this.tableForm.get('elements')?.value;` and `this.dataSource = this.tableForm.get('elements')?.value;` 
  
because this.dataSource.data not work but this.dataSource does